# ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Tags: python, numpy, multiplication

I'm trying to write this simple script but for some reason i'm struggling with the mathematical multiply operation. The error that I am getting is

```
ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

I am using PyCharm for the first time as editor and I've never had this problem with jupiter.

This is my code

```
import numpy as np


polar_surfacetension = input('Enter the polar component of the surface tension in mN/m (46.4 for water): ')
polar_dispersive = input('Enter the dispersive component of the surface tension in mN/m (26.4 for water): ')
polar_angle = list()
print("Polar Solvent measurements")
num = input("Enter numbers of measurements performed :")
print('Enter angles values in degrees: ')
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = input("Value :")
    polar_angle.append(float(n))

non_polar_surfacetension = input('Enter the  non polar component of the surface tension in mN/m (50 for \
diiodomethane): ')

print("Non Polar Solvent measurements")
non_polar_angle = list()
num_2 = input("Enter numbers of measurements performed :")
print('Enter angles values in degrees: ')
for i in range(int(num_2)):
    n = input("Value :")
    non_polar_angle.append(float(n))

solid_dispersive = (((np.cos([non_polar_angle])+1)**2)*non_polar_surfacetension)/4

print (solid_dispersive)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback of your error, as well as the values you used for your input variables that yielded the error? The example you provided does not produce any errors for me. It may be helpful to replace the `input` calls in your example with the actual values that you used when observing the error.

Comment: You are trying to multiply strings ('<U32').  So some variable(s) that you think is an array of numbers is actually an array of strings.  The most useful `numpy` debugging tool is to print array `shape` and `dtype` at the suspected problem points.

Comment: @SteveKern this is the complete error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alepe/Desktop/Wonderland/Research/REU -2016/Surface Energy Calculator.py", line 25, in <module>
    solid_dispersive = (((np.cos([non_polar_angle])+1)**2)*non_polar_surfacetension)/4
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Comment: What is `non_polar_surfacetension`?  A string, a number or what?  Don't just assume - test its value.

Comment: @hpaulj it is a number

Comment: Really?  I don't see any code that converts the `input` string to a number.

Comment: Oh, this is python3, isn't it? That changes my original assertion of not seeing an error, as I was testing the example with python 2. @hpaulj is correct, `non_polar_surfacetension` is read in by `input` as a unicode and not evaluated to anything other than that. If you want it to be a number, wrap it in a `float` or `int` like you did for your other input values.